# Passing variable to a Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass the content of a button click to a Jquery function.

My script is using "Stephan Wanger's JBox plugin" which is exceptional to create my popup..

My button code:

```
<div class="imagehelp" id="imaint_help">
  <div onClick='javascript:clickMeImage()'>
    <div class="detailButton" id="TrafficM1">
  <a href="#?Record=<?php echo $row_m['RecordID']; ?>"><img src="nav/trafficeDetail_button.png" width="91" height="59" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery function:

```
function clickMeImage() {
var record = "<?php echo $_GET['Record'];?>";
console.log(record);
new jBox('Modal', {
  attach: '.imagehelp',
  width: 1000,
  height: 500,
  title: 'Traffic detail',
  theme: 'TooltipBorder',
  closeButton: 'title',
  draggable: 'title',
  trigger: 'click',
  animation: 'false',
  position: {
    x: 'center',
    y: 'center',
  },
  offset: {x: 15, y: -10},
  onCloseComplete: function() {
    this.destroy();
    $('#jBox-overlay').remove();
  },
  ajax: {
    url: 'traffic_detail.php?RecordID=record',
    reload: 'strict'
  }
});
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'content of a button click?'

Comment: @user2233706 Hi, the content of the click button contains the content of $_GET['Record'], I hope that is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger your funtion from a parent element. I should go something like this:

```
<?php
$row_m['RecordID'] = "something";
?>
<div class="imagehelp" id="imaint_help">
    <div onClick='javascript:clickMeImage("<?php echo $row_m['RecordID']; ?>")'>
        <div class="detailButton" id="TrafficM1">
            <img src="nav/trafficeDetail_button.png" width="91" height="59"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function clickMeImage(mydata) {
        alert(mydata);
    }
</script>
```

if you want to keep the anchor, you can use an attribute:

```
    <?php
$row_m['RecordID'] = "other-something";
?>
<div class="imagehelp" id="imaint_help">
    <div onClick='javascript:clickMeImage()'>
        <div class="detailButton" id="TrafficM1">
            <a href="#" data-record="<?php echo $row_m['RecordID']; ?>"> <img src="nav/trafficeDetail_button.png" width="91" height="59"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function clickMeImage() {
        var el = document.querySelector('a');
        var mydata = el.getAttribute('data-record')
        alert(mydata);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Replace `"<?php echo $row_m['RecordID']; ?>"` with `<?=json_encode($row_m['RecordID'])?>` (no quotes outside) and you're good. Also remove the `javascript:` - in an `onclick` event, that's just a meaningless `label`.

Comment: @Alex Angelico hi, many thanks for your reply. works perfect.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol wow man, how an usefull comment!!!! why don't you just answer DCJones question

Comment: @AlexAngelico Because of everything else wrong with it, such as using inline event handlers, not making use of `data` attributes for passing data, use of `<a>` inside an element that has `onclick`... The list goes on